# Linux Mint not letting anything else boot

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot

I installed Linux Mint a few days ago. I installed it on an SSD with a system partition, a home partition, and a swap partition. On another separate SSD I have Windows 10 installed. Since installing Mint, Windows 10 doesn't boot when I select it from my motherboard's boot menu. It just boots Linux Mint. Windows also doesn't show up in grep. If I unplug the Mint SSD, the computer won't boot, since it doesn't see anything that's bootable. I tried running boot-repair, since that should theoretically repair this issue, but it doesn't boot; it just goes right into Mint.

This is what I got when I ran `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs
 2      2000GB  2000GB  472MB   primary  ntfs         diag


Model: ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA MKNSSDCR120GB-7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  120GB  120GB  ntfs         Basic data partition  msftdata


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  30.7GB  30.7GB  ext4
 2      30.7GB  46.7GB  16.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
 3      46.7GB  250GB   203GB   ext4


Error: /dev/sde: unrecognised disk label                                  

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
```

sde is the boot-repair. sdc is Windows, and sdd is Mint. I also can't browse the Windows SSD from within Mint, but GParted still shows it there.